# Adam' object has no attribute 'zero_grads'

Tags: lda, chainer

Im using a code not writing by me. So when executing this code we get error about the inexistance of zero_grads()

```
optimizer.zero_grads()
AttributeError: 'Adam' object has no attribute 'zero_grads'
```

This code is:

```
import chainer.optimizers as O
optimizer = O.Adam()
optimizer.setup(model)
clip = chainer.optimizer.GradientClipping(5.0)
optimizer.add_hook(clip)
....

optimizer.zero_grads()
optimizer.update()
```

Does i should change: `optimizer.zero_grads()` 
to

```
optimizer.use_cleargrads(use=True)?
```

Note that im using chainer 4.0 version and the code what building with chainer 1.5.

Answer (score 2):

optimizer's method `zero_grads` are deprecated and deleted, now it is preferable to use Link's method `cleargrads`.

So I guess you should change `optimizer.zero_grads()` to `model.cleargrads()`

Also, Refer

- [AttributeError: 'MomentumSGD' object has no attribute 'zero_grads'](https://github.com/chainer/chainer/issues/2971)

However, when you want to use the code written in chainer v1.5, there may be several other places you need to update for chainer v4. It might be better to try executing the code with chainer v1.5 to see the behavior at first.

Comment: With model.cleargrads() the code runs very well. You have reason about executing the code with chainer 1.5 but this version cause lot of problem. than you